# Native Mobile Test Automation Solution with Network Traffic Monitoring

Tags: android, ios, mobile, automated-tests, calabash

I would like to find a test automation solution that could let me test a native (iOS and Android) mobile app on devices and would pass/fail test cases based on the requests/responses made by the app to a backend. Calabash or Appium seem to be good contenders, but I am unsure how to setup framework and tests in either framework to succeed or fail based on external requests/responses. Any help would be appreciated.